# Multi-word aliases in bash

Tags: bash, alias

I'm trying to add a multi-word alias in my .bashrc. More specifically, I want `apt update` to be `sudo apt update -y`. But I can't figure out how to specify a multi-word alias. I've tried the following, but none of them have worked:

```
alias 'apt update'='sudo apt update -y'
alias "apt update"='sudo apt update -y'
alias apt\ update='sudo apt update -y'
```

Does someone know a way around this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Well, I get:

```
$ alias 'apt update'='sudo apt update -y'
bash: alias: 'apt update': invalid alias name
```

which seems clear enough.

Similarly, you can't have functions or commands with whitespace in their names... or well, you could, but you'd have to escape the space when using them, not fun.

The simple workaround would be to use another name instead, e.g. this should work:

```
alias apt-update='sudo apt update -y'
```

Or if you really want to, you could make `apt` a function that checks the second word (first argument) too. This should turn `apt update foo` into `sudo apt update -y foo`, just like the alias would; and would run any other commands as they were:

```
apt() {
    if [ "$1" = "update" ]; then
        shift        # eat the 'update'
        sudo apt update -y "$@"
    else 
        command apt "$@"
    fi
}
```

(Of course `apt update` doesn't take arguments, but you might want to be able to pass them for some other similar ones.)

Comment: There is also (for fun, mainly) the ugly `alias apt='sudo apt '; alias update='update -y'`, but the two aliases (taken individually) would likely be an unwanted side effect.

Comment: @fra-san, yeah, the meaning changes, but it might not be that bad here. At least as long as `update` doesn't exist as a command on its own. Most uses of `apt` require privilege anyway, and `sudo`ing something like `apt search` shouldn't be too dangerous.

Comment: "Sudoing something like `apt search` shouldn't be too dangerous." Famous last words :) Don't use `sudo` if you don't need it just because it's convenient.